# Angularjs Onbeforeunload without prompt not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onbeforeunload

I want to execute some code before the window closes but i don't want to display the prompt.
Here is my code :

```
  $window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('war-change');
        return undefined;
    };

    $scope.$on('war-change',function(){
        console.log('here');
         //Execute some more code here.
        });
```

returning undefined or false is not working as my code is not getting executed.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You code does work as intended. Check the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8ubz4bxg/

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Test unload</h2>
  <div ng-controller="unloadCtrl">
  </div>
</div>
```

And controller same as you have:

```
function unloadCtrl($scope,$window,$rootScope) {
   $window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('war-change');
        return undefined;
    };

    $scope.$on('war-change',function(){
        console.log('here');
         //Execute some more code here.
        });
}
```

But, there are limitations on what you can do with the beforeunload method, because once unload is committed, you have a very limited time to do something. To test how much time you have, you can use the following modification:

```
$scope.$on('war-change',function(){
    console.log('here');
     //Execute some more code here.
     setTimeout(function(){ console.log("ha-ha")}, 100)
     console.log("he-he")
    });
```

Now, if you decrease the timeout to something like 0-100, you may still see "ha-ha" int he output. Increase it to 2 seconds (2000) and most probably you will not see that line.